# AnimationFactory FlipTransition - Animation listener?

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm making use of this project (https://code.google.com/p/android-3d-flip-view-transition/) to do card flipping in my Android app.

Below is the code that I use to flip the card,

```
AnimationFactory.flipTransition((ViewAnimator) v,FlipDirection.LEFT_RIGHT);
```

How do I know if the animation is completed or not? I tried the below code to attach a listener for animation complete, but it throws a NullPointerException.

```
((ViewAnimator) v).getAnimation().setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

 @Override
 public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 }

 @Override
 public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

 @Override
 public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {//do something} 

});
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need create interface, and override method:

```
public static Animation[] flipAnimation
```

and set listener to `inFlip` or `outFlip` — then it will work.

Or you may define runnable when you flip view, with postDelayed — 500 ms (this time set on this project, animation time). — This option is **not** very nice, and not recommended.

EDIT:

Interface:

```
public interface FlipCompleteListener {

    public void flipOutComplete();

    public void flipInComplete();

}
```

On class AnimationFactory:

```
   private static FlipCompleteListener flipCompleteListener;

   public static void setFlipCompleteListener(FlipCompleteListener flipCompleteListener) {
        AnimationFactory.flipCompleteListener = flipCompleteListener;
    }
```

On method flipAnimation:

```
outFlip.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
             if(flipCompleteListener != null) {

             flipCompleteListener.flipOutComplete();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }
    });
```

On your class, like on create:

```
... extends Activity implements FlipCompleteListener

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AnimationFactory.setFlipCompleteListener(this);
    ...
```

And **finally** you got needed methods:

```
    @Override
    public void flipOutComplete() {
    }

    @Override
    public void flipInComplete() {
    }
```

This should work, but use static listeners — bad, need refactoring static method to object method. Project under MIT license, that allows you to do.

Comment: As you mentioned, I created an interface and override flipAnimation method, but that was not called.. Can you pls post the code that you were using?